# Win 10 doesn't recognize bluetooth headset as audio device

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, bluetooth

Hi everyone and happy new year!

Got the problem: my Win10 laptop doesn't recognize my Bluetooth headphones as audio device:

[image]

It is recognized as headset, but I can't use it as audio oder microphone deviсe. When I try to add my headphones as new BT device, Win10 understands, that's sound:
[image]

But I can't use it anyway. With Android or IOS works well.
Downloaded new drivers for my BT adapter on laptop, tried to use another drivers for headphones, anyway it is recognized as "other device".
Any ideas?

Comment: 1) go to control panel -> hardware and sound -> manage audio devices, and see if there is some device that is disabled. 2) iF that doesn't work, it's probably a driver problem. Have you asked customer support if their products support windows? It looks like a product made exclusively for cell phones and might just not work in Windows

Comment: Almost all information about this product is in Russian, which is a problem for some. Bixton does not provide any drivers for any operating system, which doesn't help.

Comment: Check all the steps in [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-bluetooth-problems-in-windows-723e092f-03fa-858b-5c80-131ec3fba75c#:~:text=If%20you%E2%80%99re%20having%20problems%20connecting%20a%20Bluetooth%20audio%20device%20or%20hearing%20sound%3A) within the section "Bluetooth accessories -> audio"